# How can I permanently purge an entire azure keyvault that's been created with soft delete enabled?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

When you create an azure keyvault with soft delete enabled that keyvault persists even if you delete it and re-create it from scratch.

> When soft-delete is enabled, resources marked as deleted resources are retained for a specified period (90 days by default). The service further provides a mechanism for recovering the deleted object, essentially undoing the deletion.

You also get this error message when you try and delete the keyvault though the UI:

> The soft delete feature has been enabled on this key vault. After you
> soft delete this key vault, it will remain in your subscription as a
> hidden vault. It will get purged after the retention period you
> specified. You may purge it sooner, or restore the vault, using Azure
> Portal, Azure PowerShell, or Azure CLI. See this page for reference:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/key-vault-ovw-soft-delete

This is causing me issues in dev. I created a keyvault with soft delete enabled (by accident) and now I want to completely remove that keyvault and re-create it with different settings. Everytime I delete it and re-create it, it includes all the previous settings, keys, etc. I also can't create a keyvault, with the same name, with soft delete disabled. It complains that a keyvault with that name already exists (`VaultAlreadyExists` exception) and that the settings are not compatible.

The [keyvault docs on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/soft-delete-overview#permitted-purge)(the link from the above message in Azure) mention how to permanently purge a soft delete but it's slightly euphemistic sentence isn't that helpful to me:

> Permanently deleting, purging, a key vault is possible via a POST
> operation on the proxy resource and requires special privileges.

So how do I get rid of this thing?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

First thing to note, as I've subsequently found out, is that [soft delete will be enabled by default by any time now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/soft-delete-change). So the *disabling* of **soft delete is now effectively deprecated**. But I still wanted to completely delete my keyvault.

---

After doing a bit of digging in the azure cli I stumbled across [this command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-purge):

```
az keyvault purge --name
                  [--location]
                  [--no-wait]
                  [--subscription]
```

So providing you are logged in with a user that has enough privilages to run this you can permanatly delete the entire key vault using the command:

```
az keyvault purge --name keyvaultname
```

This permanently and irrevocably removes the keyvault, all it's keys and settings. <strike>There doesn't seem to be a way in the Azure UI to do this without using the CLI or some other tool.</strike> It seems this is supported in the UI as well now, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/key-vault-recovery?tabs=azure-portal#list-recover-or-purge-a-soft-deleted-key-vault):

> 1. Log in to the Azure portal.
> 2. Click on the search bar at the top of the page.
> 3. Under "Recent Services" click "Key Vault". Do not click an
>    individual key vault.
> 4. At the top of the screen click the option to "Manage deleted vaults"
> 5. A context pane will open on the right side of your screen.
> 6. Select your subscription.
> 7. If your key vault has been soft deleted it will appear in the
>    context pane on the right.
> 8. If there are too many vaults, you can either click "Load More" at
>    the bottom of the context pane or use CLI or PowerShell to get the
>    results.
> 9. Once you find the vault you wish to recover or purge, select the
>    checkbox next to it.
> 10. Select the recover option at the bottom of the context pane if you
>     would like to recover the key vault.
> 11. Select the purge option if you would like to permanently delete the
>     key vault.

Comment: still can't get around purge protection. you get a "(MethodNotAllowed) Operation 'DeletedVaultPurge' is not allowed." when you attemp.

Comment: sounds like you don't have purge permissions on the resource group @ShawnCicoria

Comment: `az keyvault purge --name mykv`  == `No deleted Vault or HSM was found with name mykv`. Even though its still there. Azure is so unbelievably frustrating.

Comment: Make sure you're on the correct subscription when running that from the CLI ^. You can try from the Azure Portal now as well: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/key-vault-recovery?tabs=azure-portal

Comment: @volvox also, specify the --location parameter.

Comment: UI worked for me. CLI did not work for me.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use Az PS.
As per previous answer, this is assuming you have sufficient permissions to the subscription:

```
Remove-AzKeyVault -VaultName kvname -InRemovedState -Force -Location "Location"
```

Please see this for reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/remove-azkeyvault?view=azps-5.7.0

Also, I used this reference to get the proper order of the parameters as I wasn't familiar with switch parameters and where they go.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/14012

Comment: I don't believe this will purge the keyvault, so you'll still get the error in the question

Comment: The command worked for me

Answer (score 1):

As of July, 2023. The command

```
az keyvault purge --name keyvaultname
```

will do the work. You can go to Azure cloud shell, and type the command. It will work if your user has the privileges.